# ngx-cookie-service is not working with Angular 11 Universal SSR

Tags: angular, cookies, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-cookie-service

Currently I am switching a fully functional Client Side Angular Application into Angular Universal Server side rendering. ngx-cookie-service is not working with SSR.

Is it possible to make it work somehow. I have gone through several npm packages but not sure about its implementation or not able to decide what is best in 2021 and Angular 11.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssr-cookie
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-utils/cookies
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-universal-cookies
```

I am comfortable with ssr-cookie due to it's simplicity in implementation. But on the other end its downloads are limited.

Please suggest the best cookieservice for Universal alongwith it's implementation at client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through these node packages and few others, I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie

as most suitable and straight forward to apply CookieService